# maven plugin wont download jar in idea

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-plugin

when i use `mvn install`  comand in terminal，it s work ok.
but in idea,it work infinite repetition download file of .park suffix ,
file of .park suffix  download then change to 0 bytes, also download many times.
i change maven verison to 3.5.3, this problem it also.

idea 2020.3,maven verison 3.6.3

Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

[.park files pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elbOi.png)
[idea log pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM7MX.png)

Comment: Do you run Maven goal from the Maven tool window? Describe the exact steps you take that lead to an issue. Do you have antivirus/firewall?

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log file (Help | Show Log in ... action)?

Comment: add log pic done.

Comment: Could you please attach full idea.log after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue to the related report on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-262853 ?